# How to restart an Akka actor by self?

Tags: akka

When a child actor receives a custom RESTART message, the actor should restart itself.
(The purpose is to reset the actor member variables, reload external state from db, but not clear the actor internal message queue)

To implement the restart, one workaround is the child actor throws a custom exception, and the parent actor configures its `OneForOneStrategy` to restart the child actor for this specific exception type.

I'm wondering, if there's a more straightforward approach to do the restart?

Comment: Could you provide more details, what is meant under `restart`, please? Would you like to change actor internal state to initial one, clean message queue etc? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The purpose is to reset the actor member variables, **reload external state from db**

I guess, this is probably the biggest issue, because loading external state might take time and also blocking operation, hence result of the operation is or should be `Future[]` - so while this future loading your actor should ignore all other messages, until state from DB will be received.

I think `ActorCell#become` method might help you in this case - so you can change receive method to another, which will ignore rest of messages, except message with DB state or data, and then switch back to regular receive.

Please, see code example below:

```scala
  import akka.actor.Actor
  import akka.pattern._
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.collection.mutable


  // Database API and external state model example
  case class DbExternalState()
  trait Database {
    def loadExternalState: Future[DbExternalState]
  }

  import RestartActor._
  class RestartActor(database: Database) extends Actor {
    private var state = ActorState()
    private val suspendedMessages = mutable.Queue[Any]()

    override def receive: Receive = defaultReceive

    private def defaultReceive: Receive = {
      case Restart => restartActorStart()
    }

    /**
     * Wait until message with internal state received and ignore all the other messages (put back un queue)
     */
    private def suspendedReceive: Receive = {
      case ExternalStateLoaded(state) => restartActorFinish(state)
      case message => suspendedMessages.enqueue(message)
    }

    private def restartActorStart(): Unit = {
      import context.dispatcher
      context.become(suspendedReceive)
      database.loadExternalState.map(ExternalStateLoaded) pipeTo self
    }

    private def restartActorFinish(dbExternalState: DbExternalState): Unit = {
      state = ActorState.initial(dbExternalState)
      context.become(defaultReceive) // Return to normal message handling flow
      suspendedMessages.foreach(message => self ! message)
      suspendedMessages.clear()
    }
  }

  object RestartActor {
    // Restart
    case object Restart
    case class ExternalStateLoaded(state: DbExternalState)

    case class ActorState(internalState: List[String] = Nil, externalState: DbExternalState = DbExternalState())

    object ActorState {
      def initial(externalState: DbExternalState): ActorState = ActorState(externalState = externalState)
    }
  }
```

Please, let me know suggestions were correct.
I hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't bother me if the actor is not available during the restart, as it's quite fast. But it's better to have this. And my concern is, as the internal states are complex a little bit, restart makes it much easier for recovery. BTW: `case message => self ! message` isn't this making a `receive-resend` loop?

Comment: @user6502167 Yes, according to loop you are correct, will fix that. Regarding concern about complex state: I don't know details, but from my point of view explicit state change, looks better then throwing exception, which is not really exception or error, but expected behavior, to force system to restart an actor. What you can try to do - extract the state, if it's multiple fields, to some class with method which will return empty or default state and keep in actor only single field and change value to `default` during initialization. Does it make sens?

Comment: Right. I don't like the throw-exception approach either; that's why I'm seeking for a better solution here. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @user6502167 You are welcome. I've updated an answer as well. If you found it useful up-vote or accept also appreciated. Thank you for interesting question!